# Arduino char array prints different values

Tags: char, arduino

This problem has taken up my entire day and I can't work out why it does this. My code:

```
char products[11][14]= {   {'6','3','4','4','8','2','7','0','1','9','2','~','~'}, 
                           {'5','0','6','0','1','8','5','1','6','2','3','7','0'},
                           {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2'},
                           {'6','7','1','8','6','0','0','1','2','3','2','0','~'},
                           {'1','8','8','3','3','4','0','0','1','4','~','~','~'},
                           {'7','0','5','1','0','5','2','2','1','5','1','9','~'},
                           {'9','7','8','8','4','2','0','5','3','2','3','1','8'},
                           {'1','2','5','0','0','2','7','4','1','3','5','~','~'},
                           {'8','1','1','2','0','4','0','1','2','3','4','4','~'},
                           {'5','9','4','4','5','2','5','0','0','2','3','6','9'},
                           {'9','7','8','9','7','3','1','0','3','0','4','1','8'}
                          };
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<14; j++)
        Serial.print(products[i][j], DEC);
      Serial.println("\n");
   }
}

void loop(){}
```

When I run it, instead of printing the actual values I have stored, it prints this:

```
54515252565055484957501261260

534854484956534954505155480

484950515253545556574849500

5455495654484849505150481260

495656515152484849521261261260

5548534948535050495349571260

575556565250485351505149560

49505348485055524951531261260

5649495048524849505152521260

535752525350534848505154570

575556575551494851485249560
```

At first I figured it's the ASCII code for each one, but my values should be between 30 and 39. What is that and how do I get the actual values?

Comment: Others have already explained the details of what gets printed and why, but just as a small aside, the 30..39 range you’re thinking of is **hex**, and you’re printing in decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing out the decimal representation of the integer value of the characters in your array.

```
Serial.Print('6', DEC) // will print out '54'
```

will print out `54`, because the integer value of character '6' is 54. You can check this on [asciitable](http://www.asciitable.com)

If you want to print out the characters themselves, you should omit `DEC` and use `Print` without a second argument:

```
Serial.Print('6') // will print out '6'
```

Learn more about `Print()`'s options from [the API](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print)

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. It's late and I've been copy-pasting too much. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple.
The values are correct according to http://www.asciitable.com/.

If you want to print the char remove DEC from print

```
char products[11][14]= {   {'6','3','4','4','8','2','7','0','1','9','2','~','~'}, 
                           {'5','0','6','0','1','8','5','1','6','2','3','7','0'},
                           {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2'},
                           {'6','7','1','8','6','0','0','1','2','3','2','0','~'},
                           {'1','8','8','3','3','4','0','0','1','4','~','~','~'},
                           {'7','0','5','1','0','5','2','2','1','5','1','9','~'},
                           {'9','7','8','8','4','2','0','5','3','2','3','1','8'},
                           {'1','2','5','0','0','2','7','4','1','3','5','~','~'},
                           {'8','1','1','2','0','4','0','1','2','3','4','4','~'},
                           {'5','9','4','4','5','2','5','0','0','2','3','6','9'},
                           {'9','7','8','9','7','3','1','0','3','0','4','1','8'}
                          };
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<14; j++){
        Serial.print(products[i][j]);
        Serial.print(" ");
      }
      Serial.print("\n");
   }
}

void loop(){}
```

For example

```
Serial.print(78) gives "78"
Serial.print(1.23456) gives "1.23"
Serial.print('N') gives "N"
Serial.print("Hello world.") gives "Hello world."
Serial.print(78, BIN) gives "1001110"
Serial.print(78, OCT) gives "116"
Serial.print(78, DEC) gives "78"
Serial.print(78, HEX) gives "4E"
Serial.println(1.23456, 0) gives "1"
Serial.println(1.23456, 2) gives "1.23"
Serial.println(1.23456, 4) gives "1.2346"
```

For further information [refer to this link](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print)